# Novell, Symantec, and 802.1x

Tags: symantec, novell, 802.1

We are running Novell 4.91 sp5 with Symantec Endpoint.  We are authenticating via 802.1x and when Symantec is running we get an `802.1x Auth Fail.  RPC error occurred.  Failed to authenticate"`
We absolve the error by shutting symantec down completely OR logging in locally and then logging out and logging in via network credentials (802.1x).

We called symantec and really didn't get anywhere.  We think that the problem could lie in the snap.dll file and the way that it interacts with the NovEap.dll file.  But we have no real evidence of this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the symantec network access control program.  I disabled that service through msconfig and it worked like a charm.